# I can't use new feature ES 2020 in my next.js app

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, next.js, ecmascript-2020

I wanted to use a new feature of ES 2020 in my next.js so I used optional changes in my app. When I ran my code this error has occurred

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (50:191)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Then I ran this command

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

but the problem still exists.
Then I decided to update babel/core to version 7, I updated it via this command

```
npx babel-upgrade --write
```

but the loader error still there and I don't have any idea. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Karan",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development && SET PORT=3001 && node server.js",
        "build": "next build",
        "prod-build": "next build",
        "start": "SET NODE_ENV=production && SET PORT=8080 && node server.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^11.1.4",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.4.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "^11.2.2",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^11.0.5",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^1.1.3",
        "@fullpage/react-fullpage": "^0.1.17",
        "@sentry/browser": "^4.6.6",
        "@svgr/webpack": "^4.3.2",
        "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
        "@zeit/next-stylus": "^1.0.1",
        "axios": "^0.18.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "global": "^4.4.0",
        "jalaali-js": "^1.1.0",
        "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
        "moment-jalaali": "^0.8.3",
        "moment-jalali": "^0.3.9",
        "next": "^8.1.0",
        "next-images": "^1.1.2",
        "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
        "npm": "^6.12.1",
        "numeral": "^2.0.6",
        "persianjs": "^0.4.0",
        "pm2": "^3.5.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
        "qs": "^6.8.0",
        "react": "^16.9.0",
        "react-bootstrap-star-rating": "^3.5.5-alpha.0.3",
        "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
        "react-leaflet": "^2.4.0",
        "react-modal": "^3.9.1",
        "react-paginate": "^5.2.4",
        "react-persian-calendar": "^1.0.3",
        "react-rating": "^2.0.4",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-responsive": "^5.0.0",
        "react-select": "^2.4.4",
        "react-share": "^2.4.0",
        "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
        "react-star-ratings": "^2.3.0",
        "react-toastify": "^4.3.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "stylus": "^0.54.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.9.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
        "poststylus": "^1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your .babelrc or if you don't have one, then package.json?

Comment: @gandharvgarg Of course

Comment: that error means that you are using a file type that next.js is not familiar. so you have to load the instructions to next.js so it understans what to do. what feature do you want to use

Comment: @Yilmaz optional changing

Answer (score 0):

Since i see that you are using `next` you need to add a `.babelrc` file beside your package.json and include the below content -

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

`next/babel` includes

- preset-env
- preset-react
- preset-typescript
- plugin-proposal-class-properties
- plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
- plugin-transform-runtime
- styled-jsx

An alternative approach would be to add something similar (including the preset/transforms you need for your application) in your package.json

```
,
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "nano-react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          "loose": true
        }
      ],
      [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
        {
          "pragmaFrag": "React.Fragment"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```